# Intuition regarding: $\kappa^{+}=|\{\kappa\leq\alpha\lt \kappa^{+}\}|$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

This question is motivated by Cor. 3.7.9 in Devlin's "Joy of Sets."

The corollary says: For $\kappa\geq \aleph_0$

> > $\kappa^{+}=|\{\kappa\leq\alpha\lt \kappa^{+}\}|$
> >
> > i.e., the set of all ordinals of cardinality $\kappa$ has cardinality $\kappa^{+}$.

Does this mean that there are $\aleph_4$ ordinals ($\alpha$'s) all with the same cardinality $\aleph_3$ with $\aleph_3\leq\alpha\lt \aleph_4$.  (If it is correct that $\kappa^{+}=\aleph_4$ means $\kappa=\aleph_3$.)

What do they look like? (The foibles of a self-studier.)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building off of Asaf's answer (again!):

You also ask, re: ordinals between $\kappa$ and $\kappa^+$ (say, $\kappa=\aleph_3$),

> What do they look like?

Well, the first few look like this: $$\omega_3, \omega_3+1,\omega_3+2, ..., \omega_3\cdot 2, ..., \omega_3^2, ... \omega_3^{\omega}, ..., \omega_3^{\omega_3}, ...$$

Here $\omega_3$ is the smallest ordinal of cardinality $\aleph_3$; strictly speaking, $\omega_3$ and $\aleph_3$ are two symbols denoting the same set, but it's useful to distinguish their contexts *(especially because ordinal and cardinal arithmetic are so different, both in terms of results (cardinal arithmetic is commutative, ordinal arithmetic isn't) and in terms of definitions (ordinal exponentiation is a very different thing from cardinal exponentiation))*.

You should notice someting familiar here: this looks a lost like what we see when we try to write down some *countable* ordinals. And, just like there, we rapidly run out of easy-to-describe ordinals of the appropriate type; this is because any "reasonable" way of describing ordinals, called a "notation system," has "small fixed points" -  that is, ordinals which we care about (e.g. are smaller than $\kappa^+$) but which can't be described in a nontrivial way using that notation system. The motivating example here is the ordinal $\epsilon_0$ - this is the least ordinal $\alpha$ satisfying $\omega^\alpha=\alpha$, and is often suggestively written as $$\large\epsilon_0=\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{{}^{.^{\,\,.^{\,\,.}}}}}}}$$ - in the context of the notation system of [Cantor normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Cantor_normal_form).

The difficulty of describing large countable ordinals is discussed at [this math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496248/best-known-upper-and-lower-bounds-for-omega-1/1496269), and is I think a good starting point to understanding why it's so hard to get a "complete description" of e.g. the ordinals between $\omega_3$ and $\omega_4$.

Comment: You know that we'll have to write a book together at some point...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is exactly what it means.

One easy way to see this is to note that $\{\alpha\mid\kappa\leq\alpha<\kappa^+\}$ is exactly the set $\kappa^+\setminus\kappa$. So $\kappa^+=(\kappa^+\setminus\kappa)\cup\kappa$, as a disjoint union it means that the cardinality $\kappa^+$ is the sum of the two cardinals.

But $\kappa^+=\lambda+\kappa$ means necessarily that $\lambda=\kappa^+$.

(Another way, which is essentially the same, is noting that the ordinal sum $\kappa+\kappa$ is equipotent with $\kappa$, and repeating the essentially the same argument as above to get that the set $\kappa^+\setminus\kappa$ has size $\kappa^+$.)