# Understanding Lemma 10.2 in Munkres's Topology

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, order-theory

Lemma 10.2: There exists a well-ordered set $A$ having a largest element $\Omega$, such that the section $S_\Omega$ of $A$ by $\Omega$ is uncountable but every other section of $A$ is countable.

(1) What is being claimed in the lemma here? That we can divide/partition (English words equivalent to break) a well-ordered set into parts/sections - an uncountable and a countable part? I am not able to understand the punchline here.

(2) Is there an example for a set $B$ which I can use to understand the proof? Is $X^\omega$ where $X=\{0,1\}$, an uncountable set, well-ordered in the dictionary order (doesn't seem so though...)?

Comment: The word "section" should be explicitly defined in the earlier material on well ordering. I believe it means an initial interval in the given well ordering. As for a specific example, I suspect it's not going to be so concrete (otherwise we probably wouldn't need to call it a lemma!).

Comment: "Is $X^\omega$ where $X=\{0,1\}$, an uncountable set, well-ordered in the dictionary order (doesn't seem so though...)?" If you have a set with size $|\Bbb R|$, you _can't_ explicitly construct a well-order on it. The closest you can get is to use the continuum hypothesis or the axiom of choice to declare that one exists.

Comment: perhaps it is easiest to consider the analogous situation with countable well-ordered sets. let $\omega$ denote the set of natural numbers, and consider the set $A:=\omega\cup\{\infty\}$ with the convention $n<\infty$ for all $n\in\omega$. I will leave it to you to check that $A$ is well-ordered. $A$ has largest element $\infty$, and the section of $A$ by $\infty$ is the *infinite* subset $\omega\subset A$. however, for any other $a\in A$, if $a\neq\infty$ then $a\in\omega$ is a natural number, and the section of $A$ by $a$ is the *finite* subset $\{0,\dots,a-1\}\subset A$

Comment: @GregMartin It's actually more specific than that, if memory serves: it refers to sets only of the form $\{x:x<a\}$ for some element of the ordering $a$. (If we used the broader notion, we'd have to get rid of $\Omega$ since $\{x: x<\Omega\}$ and $\{x:x\le\Omega\}$ are distinct uncountable initial segments of $A$.)

Answer (score 3):

Re: your first question, I think the stumbling point is terminological: "section" is a technical term in Munkres, referring to sets of the form $\{x: x<a\}$ for some element of the ordering $a$. The introduction of this term is easy to overlook at first, which makes statements about sections seem either mysterious or trivial.

I think it may help to rephrase the lemma as follows:

> There is a well-ordering $A$ with **exactly one element** $a$ such that $\{x: x<a\}$ is uncountable.

As to your second question, unfortunately this is a rather complicated object. For example, the usual axioms of set theory *cannot* decide whether it has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$. (For example, it's a good exercise to show that $\{0,1\}^\omega$ with the lexicographic order is not well-ordered *and* has lots of uncountable sections.)

It can be "explicitly constructed," but that explicit construction is rather abstract; the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1496248/28111) is relevant *(although it refers to the version of $A$ with the "top element" removed)*. Understanding this object is an important and meaningfully difficult step in the process of learning "intermediate" set theory; for a first course in point-set topology, it's really only touched on and is *used* more than it is *understood* (FWIW I think there's a vague analogy with the role of Zorn's lemma in abstract algebra courses).

Comment: so an extension of what you are saying is that in every well-ordered set they is exactly one subset that is a section and also uncountable? Why is this important to know?

Comment: @DonaldObama No, in **this particular** well-ordered set there is exactly one uncountable section. As to why it's important, it's important for understanding "long" transfinite recursions (such as the construction of the **Borel hierarchy**) and also shows up in various examples/counterexamples in topology (this is how it will appear primarily in Munkres, if I recall correctly).

Comment: So, when you say, this particular well-ordered set, what makes it particular? Having  $\Omega$, a largest element in a well-ordered set? Is the subset of this uncountable section countable, then? I think I am getting closer to some-what understanding it, many thanks.